# Any way to make XmlSerializer output xml in a defined order?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Currently I'm using XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize an object. The xml is generated in an undefined order which is understandable but makes it annoying when comparing versions of the object, since the order of properties is different each time. So for instance I can't use a normal diff tool to see any differences.

Is there an easy way to generate my xml in the same order every time, without writing the ReadXml and WriteXml methods myself? I have a lot of properties on the class, and add new ones every now and again, so would prefer to not have to write and then maintain that code.

(C# .net 2.0)

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces this "undefined order"? I've never seen it happen, and I don't see how the XML Serializer would be able to deserialize the result if it did happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The XmlElement attribute has an [order property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order.aspx). You can use that as a start.

If you need to find the diff in Xml files, you might want to take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Decorate your properties with the [XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx), setting the [Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order.aspx) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

ps: I don't believe the XML generated by the XmlSerializer is in an undefined order.  It may be undocumented, but it is known.  I believe that in the absence of Order attributes, the XmlSerializer serializes all public Properties, alpha-sorted by prop name, and then all public Fields, alpha-sorted by name.