# Sorting the output from XmlSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, xml-serialization

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013435/changing-the-xml-structure-generated-by-xmlserializer-in-c), I could get an XML file generated based on C# class.

Can I reorder the XML elements based on its element? My code uses

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Module));
ser.Serialize(WriteFileStream, report, ns);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

to get the XML file, but I need to have the XML file sorted based on a BlocksCovered variable.

```
public class ClassInfo {
    public string ClassName;
    public int BlocksCovered;
    public int BlocksNotCovered;
    public double CoverageRate;

    public ClassInfo() {}

    public ClassInfo(string ClassName, int BlocksCovered, int BlocksNotCovered, double CoverageRate) 
    {
        this.ClassName = ClassName;
        this.BlocksCovered = BlocksCovered;
        this.BlocksNotCovered = BlocksNotCovered;
        this.CoverageRate = CoverageRate;
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Module")]
public class Module {
    [XmlElement("Class")]
    public List<ClassInfo> ClassInfoList;
    public int BlocksCovered;
    public int BlocksNotCovered;
    public string moduleName;

    public Module()
    {
        ClassInfoList = new List<ClassInfo>();
        BlocksCovered = 0;
        BlocksNotCovered = 0;
        moduleName = "";
    }
}

Module report = new Module();

...

TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(xmlFileName);
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Module));
ser.Serialize(WriteFileStream, report, ns);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

### SOLVED

```
public void Sort()
{
    ClassInfoList = ClassInfoList.OrderBy( x=>x.CoverageRate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: if your `ClassInfoList` is sorted already (as your previous question implies it is now), is the output XML produced by the `XmlSerializer` not sorted? I would be surprised

Comment: @BrokenGlass : The ClassInfoList not sorted at all, I need to get a sorted output from unsorted ClassInfoList.

Comment: well - why don't you sort it before serializing? That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to make XmlSerializer output xml in a defined order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612160/any-way-to-make-xmlserializer-output-xml-in-a-defined-order)

Comment: @Jon: not a duplicate OP wants the contents of a list element to be sorted, not the  elements of his class

Comment: @Jon et. al. Not a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sort your list before serializing, it appears in your code that you have control over the serialization - if that is the case just sort the `ClassInfoList` list before serializing your Module by adding a `Sort()` method:

```
public class Module
{

  public void Sort()
  {
      ClassInfoList = ClassInfoList.OrderBy( x=>x.BlocksCovered).ToList();
  }
..
}
```

then call Sort() before serializing:

```
report.Sort();
ser.Serialize(WriteFileStream, report, ns);
```

If you don't have control over when/and how your class is serialized have your Module class implement `IXmlSerializable` and sort within your `Serialize()` method - the later is more effort though and should be avoided.

Comment: ClassInfoList = ClassInfoList.OrderBy( x=>x.BlocksCovered).ToList(); solved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @prosseek: Ah yes, that was a copy&paste omission from the previous solution, updated the answer - glad you caught it

Comment: If I want to sort descending order? What should be changed?

Comment: just use `ClassInfoList = ClassInfoList.OrderByDescending( x=>x.BlocksCovered).ToList();` instead